# What is Widget Layer?

Tags: 12.04, compiz, widgets

I was looking through the settings in Compiz and I found this:

[image: Widget Layer]

I have no idea what it does as I have pressed <kbd>F9</kbd> and it just made my screen dim (the kind you get when Ubuntu isn't responding), but now I want to know how to use it properly.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 3):

> The **Widget Layer** plugin provides functionality to show and hide your widgets at will. You can define what windows are widgets and press a key / mouse button or screen edge to show them.

Source and more about: http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Widget

---

I didn't understand well what exactly does this plugin until I wasn't in Behaviour tab to add a new widget window. I grabbed, for example, my gnome-terminal window and then I was played with <kbd>F9</kbd> key to see what is happening.

[image: Widget Layer]